# Webcam visible but "no frame" on VMWare Ubuntu guest

Tags: ubuntu, usb, webcam, framebuffer, vmware-player

I have asked this question previously. But I tried to do more research before posting it again. Here's the issue :

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on VMWare 6.0 with Windows 7 as host.
I am trying to access my webcam on Ubuntu but I'm successful only once in a while.

The results for lsusb is :

```
harsh@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

But when I run applications like "cheese" or "qv4l2", I get errors like :

(qv4l2)

```
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Broken pipe
Start Capture: Broken pipe
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

(cheese)

```
** (cheese:3230): WARNING **: Error starting streaming on device '/dev/video0'.
** (cheese:3230): WARNING **: Could not negotiate format
```

(uvcdynctrl)

```
harsh@ubuntu:~$ uvcdynctrl --list
Listing available devices:
  video0   HD Pro Webcam C920
  Media controller device /dev/media0 doesn't exist
ERROR: Unable to list device entities: Invalid device or device cannot be opened. (Code: 5)
```

(hwinfo)

```
harsh@ubuntu:~$hwinfo --usb
//specific to camera
06: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
[Created at usb.122]
UDI: /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_46d_82d_7AA010EF_if0_logicaldev_input
Unique ID: ADDn.nbyTPNaHH35
Parent ID: k4bc.Qnlx_VAX744
SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
SysFS BusID: 1-1:1.0
Hardware Class: unknown
Model: "Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x046d "Logitech, Inc."
Device: usb 0x082d "HD Pro Webcam C920"
Revision: "0.11"
Serial ID: "7AA010EF"
Driver: "uvcvideo"
Driver Modules: "uvcvideo"
Device File: /dev/input/event3
Device Files: /dev/input/event3, /dev/input/by-id/usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_7AA010EF-  event-if00, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:02:03.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event
Device Number: char 13:67
Speed: 480 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v046Dp082Dd0011dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc01ip00in00"
Driver Info #0:
  Driver Status: uvcvideo is active
  Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe uvcvideo"
Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
Attached to: #5 (Hub)`
```

(v4l2-ctl)

```
harsh@ubuntu:~$ v4l2-ctl -D
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
Driver name   : uvcvideo
Card type     : HD Pro Webcam C920
Bus info      : usb-0000:02:03.0-1
Driver version: 3.8.13
Capabilities  : 0x84000001
    Video Capture
    Streaming
```

(dmesg)

```
harsh@ubuntu:~$dmesg
[ 1978.311511] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1982.231881] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 1982.541344] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=082d
[ 1982.541350] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[ 1982.541353] usb 1-1: Product: HD Pro Webcam C920
[ 1982.541356] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 7AA010EF
[ 1982.547236] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HD Pro Webcam C920 (046d:082d)
[ 1982.556504] input: HD Pro Webcam C920 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input5
```

I have even tried the `LD_PRELOAD` solution as well, but same results.
Would like any insight on this.

Comment: I tried removing the uvcvideo module and installing it again. First time it worked but no success after that :(

Comment: I tried the same setup on a friend's computer. I disabled VMWare USB auto-connect. Everytime no frames are seen, I manually disconnect and connect the webcam from settings and it works. But this does not work on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue a few days ago, and it is fixed by changing USB 2.0 to USB 3.0 of VMware setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Cheese on Debian in my Vmware, Loom's Answer in the link below solved my problem :

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/454220/ubuntu-14-04-cheese-booth-not-detect-webcam

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the webcam is not connected to vm machine directly like other USB devices. So here's how I use it on virtualbox.

1. Close your guest OS.
2. Open USB settings of your vm in virtual box. Make sure USB 2.0 (OHCI and EHCI) is enabled and you can add the camera device from usb filters. If it is jump to step 6.
3. If you don't see your webcam listed under USB 2.0 settings, then you need to add virtualbox extensions pack. It's pretty simple step just follow this - https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/intro-installing.html
4. You can also use terminal/cmd on host to check the detected webcam devices and attach/detach webcam. Follow the instructions here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/webcam-passthrough.html Although this approach is no longer required on latest versions of 6.0 or above
5. Restart your VM so the settings are updated and you can see your webcam in the list. If not try restarting the host machine.

That is all there's is to be configured on the host side.

6. Power up your vm and login.
7. Now find your webcam under webcam settings in virtualbox settings panel and enable it. Also make sure the same webcam is selected under the USB devices as well.

Now you should be able to use your webcam on guest machine as well.

8. At this point if you still can not see the camera stream in your viewer (i.e. empty/black stream), chances are you're using cheese viewer.

Open up your terminal and run:

## sudo apt-get install -y guvcview

## guvcview

I assume that cheese has some issues in supporting certain UVC class webcam, which should work just fine with guvcview.